# Laravel 6 - My Route doesnt work in Resource Controller

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes

I have a Admincontroller. Here I can do a simple CRUD function.

With this route: `Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');`

Everything (create, edit destroy) works perfect.

Now I have a new function in this Controller.

Named deactivate. Here i can deactivate users.

this is the function:

```
public function deactivate($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        if ($user->verified == 1){
            $user->verified = 0;
            $user->save();
            $angebot = Angebot::where('firma', $id);
            $angebot->delete();
            return redirect('/admin')->with('success', 'Nutzer wurde erfolgreich deaktiviert');
        }

        if($user->verified == 0){
            $user->verified = 1;
            $user->save();
            return redirect('/admin')->with('success', 'Nutzer wurde erfolgreich aktiviert');
        }

    }
```

for this function i have this route:

```
Route::get('admin/{id}', 'AdminController@deactivate')->name('admin.deactivate');
```

in my view it looks like this:

`<a href="{{ route('admin.deactivate',$user->id)}}">`

if i click on this link it goes to /admin/2 (so it gives me the right id)

but it doesnt redirekt to /admin so i think the route doesnt work because the function should work

does anyone know why?

is it because i do this in my ressource controller?

Comment: If you need to add additional routes to a resource controller beyond the default set of resource routes, you should define those routes before your call to `Route::resource; `otherwise, the routes defined by the resource method may unintentionally take precedence over your supplemental routes:

Comment: ah thank you!!!  everythign works perfect :)))

Comment: if the answer is useful..mark it as useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want to add an extra route to your resource route,add it above the resource route..

```
 Route::get('admin/{id}', 'AdminController@deactivate')->name('admin.deactivate');
 Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
```